# On $C(K)$ spaces embeddable into the Banach space $c_0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Problem 1.** Characterize compact Hausdorff spaces $K$ for which the Banach space $C(K)$ of continuous real-valued functions embeds into the Banach space $c_0$.

Since $c_0$ has separable dual, such $K$ must me countable. So, we can make Problem 1 more precise:

> **Problem 2.** Is it true that for every compact countable space $K$ the Banach space $C(K)$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $c_0$?

Another possible option:

> **Problem 3.** Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Is it true that the Banach space $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $c_0$ if $C(K)$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $c_0$?

Comment: Problem 3: $K$ finite makes trivial counterexamples. Surprisingly (?) the answer is yes for $K$ infinite according to Tomek Kania's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Szlenk index is the answer.

A space $C(K)$, where $K$ is infinite compact Hausdorff space, is embeddable into $c_0$ if and only if $K$ is homeomorphic to an ordinal below $\omega^\omega$ and if this is the case (and $K$ is infinite) the space itself is isomorphic to $c_0$.

So the answer to problem 2 is no however the answer to problem 3 is yes.

For details see Rosenthal's chapter in the Handbook of Banach spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Rosenthal, Haskell P.
The Banach spaces C(K). Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces, Vol. 2, 1547-1602, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2003.